# equals() and hashcode() methods in java

Tags: java

Another question from the same homework:

```
//attributes:
public int identifikace;
public String druh;
public int vek;
public Majitel majitel;

//constructor:
public Zvire(int identifikace, String druh, int vek, Majitel majitel){
    this.identifikace = identifikace;
    this.druh = druh;
    this.vek = vek;
    this.majitel = majitel;
```

Some simple getters etc. Now what I should do: "Into class Zvire, add methods equals() and hashcode() implemented so two *Zvire* are same if they have same *identifikace* attribute." (not an ideal translation but you probably get the point)

I would probably be able to figure it out, but I'm starting to be in a hurry. Would anyone mind going through it very simply?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: if you want to derive the hash code from an attribute, that attribute should be either final or at least logically immutable (i.e. you never set it, and you don't allow anybody else to set it). Public attributes can be changed anywhere, and that would break hash-based data structures containing the instance.

Comment: In this simple example, this is not a Problem but: Start to give your variables english names. It makes it easier for other People to read and understand your Code!

Comment: If my answer below is good enough for you don't hesitate to mark is as best response, thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ask your IDE to do it for you, here is what you get from IntelliJ:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    final Zvire zvire = (Zvire) o;
    return this.identifikace == zvire.identifikace;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.identifikace);
}
```

Comment: ... but that takes pressing three keys ... ;) +1

Comment: @Nicolas Don't laugh. Some programmers are old, and have no elastic fingers anymore.

Comment: @Martin That's right, but I don't believe that is the case here as it is for an homework and old programers don't do homework anymore :-)